# Word for "people with write-access"

Tags: word-choice

Say you have a forum only a select group of people have access to contribute to - what would you call those people?

Or, more accurately to my domain, say you have a file on a shared computer drive that any user can read but only certain users can write to - what would you call those certain users?

Comment: Generally, I would call them **contributors** or **editors**.

Comment: *Co-conspirators?*

Answer (score 3):

- *authors*
- *contributors*
- *writers*
- *editors*

Your choice may depend on how many levels of access you will have in total.

Comment: "Editors" is probably the most general of these in application.

Comment: yes, but if there are to be multiple levels of access then *editors* tells us that they have access to make changes to things already written, while the other choices might simply have access to write things.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a cue from classic [pub-sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) terminology, I'd call such people "***publishers***".